# Cant find the issue that causes error of mysql statement

Tags: mysql, database

So for this specific mysql that I have, I try to join the 2 tables together then pick out the names that have max values in another column in the joined table. I suspect the issue is where I connect 2 statements together.

```
select ds_name
from result 
where result.ds_sectionnumber = (select max(ds_sectionnumber) from result) 
from (select department.Dcode as ds_code, department.Dname as ds_name, section.Sectionnumber as ds_sectionnumber 
from department join section on department.Dcode = section.Dcode) as result;
```

Comment: And the `error of MySQL statement` is? Looks like you are using too many `FROM`s

Comment: your syntax is completely wrong. You cannot have from clause after you are done with subquery. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: So many `FROM`s?? Wow! Provide schema and explain clearly what you wanr as result for a better answer!

Comment: result is the merged table of the other 2, I was trying to get the name of any row that has the highest section # value, which is a field in result. Sorry, I'm really new to mysql.

Comment: Before you read the chapter on subqueries, try reading the chapter on joins.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query should be this:

```
select ds_name
  FROM (select department.Dcode as ds_code,
               department.Dname as ds_name, 
               section.Sectionnumber as ds_sectionnumber 
        FROM department 
        JOIN section on department.Dcode = section.Dcode) as result
  WHERE ds_sectionnumber = (
            select max(ds_sectionnumber) FROM 
                  (select department.Dcode as ds_code,
                     department.Dname as ds_name, 
                    section.Sectionnumber as ds_sectionnumber 
                       FROM department 
                       JOIN section 
                      ON department.Dcode = section.Dcode) as result);
```

Comment: somehow it says the table result doesn't exist for me.

Comment: @Rozen try without where clause and its condition hope this comes from where clause.

Comment: without where clause, it give me the ds_name without the condition of max sectionnumber though. I'm not really sure where it is wrong either since the syntax is correct.

Comment: @Rozen I have updated the answer now check it again it will work for you.

Comment: yea... I need to work on getting things together right...  the way I been doing it seems to be horribly wrong.

Comment: @Strawberry this is open forum you can edit the post and can change but remember that should be workable.

Comment: No, no. Not without seeing some DDLs